# BeginInvoke Alternative in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to port a class in C# that inherits from the class `Form` . To another class that does not inherit from `Form`. I am having an issue porting this method

```
this.BeginInvoke(new ThreadSafeDisposeChromeAndCreateNewDelegate(this.ThreadSafeDisposeChromeAndCreateNew), processWindow, maximized);
```

The problem is with `this.BeginInvoke` I am not fluent with C# however I understand that this is because my class does not inherit from Form. My question is - is it possible to restructure the above statement for a class that does not inherit from `Form`

Comment: Try `TaskFactory.StartNew()` or `Task.Run()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's different unless you pass `TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext()` (which is captured in UI thread)

Answer (score 0):

`Form.BeginInvoke` (or, more generally, `Control.BeginInvoke`) executes the delegate *on the user interface thread*.

Thus, to do the same here, you need *some* reference to your form or some other control on it, so that the framework can ensure that the correct thread is chosen.

As soon as you have the reference, you can just execute

```
myReference.BeginInvoke(...);
```